# Map an object array with unknown length and unknown key names

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Here are some object arrays:

```
1. [{id:'1', code:'somecode', desc:'this is the description'}, {...}, {...}]

2. [{fname:'name', lname:'last name', address:'my address', email:'my@email.com'}, {...}, {...}]
```

What I need to do is create a function where I pass an array and map their object keys to generic keys so they become like this:

```
1. [{key1:'1', key2:'somecode', key3:'this is the description'}, {...}, {...}]

2. [{key1:'name', key2:'last name', key3:'my address', key4:'my@email.com'}, {...}, {...}]
```

When I do this

```
let keys: string[] = Object.keys(this.options[0])
this.replacedItems = this.options.map(item => {
  return{
    key1: item[keys[0]],
    key2: item[keys[1]],
    key3: item[keys[2]],
  }
});
```

it works fine, but since the object's properties number is not fixed, I tried this

```
let keys: string[] = Object.keys(this.options[0])
this.replacedItems = this.options.map(item => {
  let i=0;
  keys.forEach(key=>{
    let newKey = 'key'+i;
    i++
    return { newKey: item[key] }
  });
});
```

which rerurns an array of undefined...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You try to `return` from inside the `forEach` callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the second parameter of `.map` to get the current index you're iterating over, and concatenate it with `'key'`. You can also use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys` to get the values immediately (since you're not actually using the original keys):

```js
const options = [{id:'1', code:'somecode', desc:'this is the description'}];
const replacedItems = options.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.values(obj).map((val, i) => ['key' + (i + 1), val])
));
console.log(replacedItems);
```